# Как вернуть из метода значение String'a

Tags: java

Только учусь Джаве и делаю маленькую текстовую игру и в начале игрок может написать своё имя, которое в последствии будет участвовать в диалогах.
Я написал метод, который присваивает стрингу введённое пользователем значение:

```
public static void MainCharacter() {
        System.out.println("*Введите ваше имя*");
        Scanner MainCharacterScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String MainCharacterName = MainCharacterScanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Я так понимаю, надо использовать оператор return, чтобы этот метод возвращал значение переменной MainCharacterNamе, но как это сделать - не понимаю, а все примеры по return в гугле основаны на числах.

Comment: дак и делайте по примерам, просто вместо int у вас будет стоять String. В вашем примере надо заменить void на String и в конце метода написать return MainCharacterName.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, с оператором return разобрался, надеюсь окончательно)

Comment: Попробуйте вначале почитать какую то литературу по java. Большинство простых вопросов сразу отпадет.

Comment: @temq начинал учить с Head First Java, но уж больно она мне показалась странной в плане преподнесения информации, по этому начал учиться, делая небольшие проектики, попутно изучая материал по Java на русском языке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String MainCharacter() {
    System.out.println("*Введите ваше имя*");
    Scanner MainCharacterScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String MainCharacterName = MainCharacterScanner.nextLine();
    return MainCharacterName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Параметр `void` обозначает, что данный метод не возвращает никаких значений. Если необходимо что бы он вернул какое либо значение, вместо `void` необходимо указать тип объекта, который будет возвращён. 
В вашем случае это `String`. Так же это может быть и примитивный тип. К примеру Integer для int.

```
 public static String MainCharacter() {
return MainCharacterName;
}
```

Соответственно так будет записано значение в переменную:

```
 String s=MainCharacter();
```